# fullcalendar.js auto selected and check box available

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have role.

1. when user click block box. box will be selection 2 box after box clicked (like drag selected by mouse).
2. if 2 box have one or more union some event. selected to fail. (make sure 2 box is available box) but i stuck how to do it.

i want to build registration building for event. and this is interface to get time to registration.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            selectable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            allDaySlot: false,
            editable: false,
            selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
                var duration = moment.duration(selectInfo.end.diff(selectInfo.start));
                console.log(selectInfo.end);
                return duration.asHours() <= 1;
            },
            selectMinDistance: 0,
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {},
            validRange: function(nowDate) {
                nowDate = nowDate.clone().add(-1, 'day');
                return {
                    start: nowDate,
                    end: nowDate.clone().add(1, 'months')
                };
            },
            businessHours: [{
                dow: [1], // Monday - Friday
                start: '08:00',
                end: '12:00',
            }, {
                dow: [4, 5], // Monday - Friday (if adding lunch hours)
                start: '13:00',
                end: '17:00',
            }],
            selectConstraint: "businessHours",
            resources: [{
                id: 'b',
                title: '',
                eventColor: 'green'
            }, ],
            events: [{
                    id: '2',
                    resourceId: 'b',
                    start: '2018-10-27T09:00:00',
                    end: '2018-10-27T10:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: '3',
                    resourceId: 'b',
                    start: '2018-11-28T12:00:00',
                    end: '2018-11-28T06:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: '4',
                    resourceId: 'b',
                    start: '2018-10-29T07:30:00',
                    end: '2018-10-29T09:30:00'
                },
                {
                    id: '5',
                    resourceId: 'b',
                    start: '2018-10-29T10:00:00',
                    end: '2018-10-29T15:00:00'
                }
            ],
            select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
                console.log(
                    'select ted',
                    start.format(),
                    end.format(),
                    resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
                );
            },
        });
    });
```

i have snippet

```js
$(function() { // document ready
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    allDaySlot: false,
    editable: false,
    selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
     var duration = moment.duration(selectInfo.end.diff(selectInfo.start));
     console.log(selectInfo.end);
     return duration.asHours() <= 1;
    },
    selectMinDistance: 0,
    header: {
     left: 'prev',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'next'
    },
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {},
    validRange: function(nowDate) {
     nowDate = nowDate.clone().add(-1, 'day');
     return {
      start: nowDate,
      end: nowDate.clone().add(1, 'months')
     };
    },
    businessHours: [{
     dow: [1], // Monday - Friday
     start: '08:00',
     end: '12:00',
    }, {
     dow: [4, 5], // Monday - Friday (if adding lunch hours)
     start: '13:00',
     end: '17:00',
    }],
    selectConstraint: "businessHours",
    resources: [{
     id: 'b',
     title: '',
     eventColor: 'green'
    }, ],
    events: [{
      id: '2',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2018-10-27T09:00:00',
      end: '2018-10-27T10:00:00'
     },
     {
      id: '3',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2018-11-28T12:00:00',
      end: '2018-11-28T06:00:00'
     },
     {
      id: '4',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2018-10-29T07:30:00',
      end: '2018-10-29T09:30:00'
     },
     {
      id: '5',
      resourceId: 'b',
      start: '2018-10-29T10:00:00',
      end: '2018-10-29T15:00:00'
     }
    ],
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
     console.log(
      'select ted',
      start.format(),
      end.format(),
      resource ? resource.id : '(no resource)'
     );
    },
   });
  });
```

```css
 .fc-time-grid .fc-event,
  .fc-time-grid .fc-bgevent {
   width: calc(100% + 4px);
   margin-left: -2px;
   border-radius: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/scheduler.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/scheduler.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="calendar"></div>
 
</body>

</html>
```